# What is a changelog?

Tags: downloads, terminology

I am a relatively new Ubuntu user and want to know what a changelog is, and how to use it. It seems to come in response to some downloads, and I can't understand what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you are asking.
Do you mean that some of your downloads come with a changelog?

A changelog to me is a log of changes along with other details like who made the change, what changes were made, and its purpose. I see it often as text files in software downloads, and on websites that host OSes and softwares.

Here are some examples of a changelog.
*(I understand better by example, so I'll explain this way.)*

---

### Example 1

For example, take a look here for the changelog of the Linux Kernel.

[Linux Kernel Changelog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ChangeLog-3.12.8)

You see a list of the changes that were applied to the Kernel from its previous release.

-

### Example 2

Here's another changelog for comparison.

[Raspberry Pi Changelog](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-3.10.y/Documentation/Changes)

See how the format is very different. Here, the file is called Changes.

---

Also, a changelog is sometimes embedded into a compiled program and is accessible via the interface. There's no specific standard for formatting of the text, and can be referred to as different names. (Changes, Changelog, Updates, etc.)

I hope that answers your question. If not, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

A *ChangeLog* presents a record of changes that have been incorporated to a software in the current as well as in the previous versions. It mentions name of every files changed along with changes in functions, rules, etc. in the program codes and possibly include the reasons why. They include information about bug-fixes, features added/removed/modified in the program, and others. You can find such included with the source code archives/tarballs in the open source projects. It includes information about the patches used in the program and the name of the contributors.

#### Reference:

- [changelog: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changelog)